# Creating a javascript object Using object initializers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kind a new in Javascript and I have this situation:
I have a separated javascript file and I created a javascript object in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var formasPagamento = {
        Cartao: 0,
        Crediario: 1,
        Vale: 2
    };
});
```

In this same file, I have a function and I want to use this object formasPagamento, but when I try to use it, I get the error that formasPagamento is undefined.

Ex:

```
function CarregarDetalhesPlanoPagamento(idPosDocPagamento) {    
     if(idPosDocPagamento == formasPagamento.Cartao){ //undefined here
         //do something
     }
}
```

What's the proper way to initializa a "global" variable that can be used in another function?

Comment: define `var formasPagamento` outside of `$(document).ready(function () {` scope

Comment: or if you're lazy just remove `var` and you don't have to move it.

Comment: Thanks guys, i didn't pay attention in this detail.
I'll never make this mistake again because of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wrap var formasPagamento inside of $(document).ready. That is placing it inside of a child scope of global, making it inaccessible from your function. $(document).ready is to detect when the DOM is ready to be manipulated and there's no reason to postpone declaring that value.

Comment: I didn't pay attention in this detail. After putting out the document.ready, it's working now!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What's the proper way to initializa a "global" variable that can be
>   used in another function?

```
window.formasPagamento = {
    Cartao: 0,
    Crediario: 1,
    Vale: 2
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you're declaring `formasPagamento` inside the `document.ready` `jQuery` wrapper, so `formasPagamento` can only be accessed from within that function.

This is known as scope.

To be able to access `formasPagamento` globally, you can declare it before your `$(document).ready..` like so:

```
var formasPagamento = {
    Cartao: 0,
    Crediario: 1,
    Vale: 2
};

$(document).ready(function () {    
   ..page ready logic..
});
```

Now when you use your function, it'll be able to see `formasPagamento`

Comment: I didn't pay attention in this detail. After putting out the document.ready, it's working now!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This article explains it quite well [w3School](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)
But basically the variable `formasPagamento` is only accessible inside the function scope of the document ready function.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var formasPagamento {};
    // CAN access here!
}
// CANNOT access here!
```